# Simple first order differentiation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested in pricing optimization and I came across [this article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/pricing-optimization-how-to-find-the-price-that-maximizes-your-profit/) which does a nice job explaining things.

I am trying to follow the total revenue example but when it comes to the differentiation I become stuck (it's been a while).

Taking $~R(p) = \alpha.p^2 + p.\beta~$ and taking the first order differentiation should I not have $$~P_{\text{max rev}} = 2.\alpha.p^1 + p.\beta~?$$

How do we get to $~-\dfrac{\beta}{2.\alpha}~$, please excuse my ignorance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$R(p)=p^2 \alpha+p\beta$$
Remember the rule:
$$(p^n)'=np^{n-1}$$
Differentiate w.r.t $p$ :
$$R'(p)=2p \alpha +\beta$$
We want the extrema so the derivative is zero  :
$$R'(p)=0$$
$$2p_{max} \alpha +\beta=0$$
$$p_{max}=- \dfrac {\beta}{ 2\alpha }$$
Since the curve is concave then it's a maximum